# How to load a template text file in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have a template fragment file, which is an xml file in fact.

I want to load it in my controller, do some modification on that, and then use it to render some part of the view.

I only need to read this xml file as text file and put its content in a string.

I cannot find any object for doing this in SAPUI5 api.

Please note the file is placed in my view folder in server side.

I need some kind of promise that read the file and after reading the file run a successor function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to to this.

1.Either you can load your XML in an XML Model "`sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel()`"

```
var oModelX = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel(); 
oModelX.attachRequestCompleted(function(){
    var xmlStr =  oModelX.getXML();
    console.log(xmlStr); // Do what ever you want with your xml string 
}); 
oModelX.loadData("../view/st.fragment.xml");
```

2.You can also read the content of that XML file using AJAX and do your parsing in AJAX response.